# How can I print extremely many data windows in power builder without app crashing

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am trying to print over 2000 reports using PrintDataWindow as [described here](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc37781_1150/html/psref/BFCDAEGC.htm), The problem is that when app runs, It prints upto 100 records then freezes, Is there another better/optimal way I can use with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting a Yield() function after each instance of PrintDataWindow?  This will allow the application to collect itself and let other processes run.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Yield() and then GarbageCollect() after each instance of PrintDatawindow.

This issue mostly happens because your app is most probably a 32-bit application which cannot handle more than 2 GB of data. While you are printing 2000 reports the application is never idle so GarbageCollect() never runs, so the objects created are never destroyed. So putting the Garbagecollect() should solve your problem.